# Taylor's theorem in Gelfand/Fomin's Calculus of Variations

Tags: taylor-expansion, variational-analysis

There is one deduction on page 14 I don't seem to be able to understand. It has been established that the increment of the functional can be expressed as:

$$\Delta J = \int_a^b \left[F\left(x, y+h, y^\prime + h^\prime\right) - F\left(x, y, y^\prime\right)\right] dx$$

This is supposedly equal to:

$$\int_a^b \left[F_y\left(x, y, y^\prime\right) h + F_{y^\prime} \left(x, y, y^\prime\right) h^\prime\right] dx + \cdots$$

Here, the dots "denote terms of order higher than 1 relative to $h$ and $h^\prime$" and this is supposed to (easily) follow from Taylor's theorem, but I don't see how. Can anyone explain this step to me?

Comment: $$F(x,y+h,y'+h')=F(x,y,y') + 0\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,y') + h\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y,y') + h'\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}(x,y,y')+\text{higher order terms}$$

Comment: Thanks @jlammy, your comment cleared it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, misreading the text tripped me up. I edited in a missing prime, and with @jlammy's comment, everything makes sense now. We are evaluating $J[y] = \int_a^b F(x, y, y')\ dx$ at $J[y+h] = \int_a^b F(x, y+h, y'+h')\ dx$, and as far as the Taylor polynomial is concerned, we expand $T_1F$ around $(x,y,y')$. This gives:

\begin{align}
T_1F &= F(x, y, y') \\
&\phantom{=} + \frac{\delta F}{\delta x}(x, y, y') (x-x) + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(x, y, y') (y+h-y) + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y'}(x, y, y') (y'+h'-y') \\
&= F(x, y, y') + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(x, y, y') h + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y'}(x, y, y') h'
\end{align}

So $F(x, y+h, y'+h') = F(x, y, y') + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(x, y, y') h + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y'}(x, y, y') h' + \cdots$

Now,

\begin{align}
\Delta J = J[y+h]-J[y] &= \int_a^b F(x, y+h, y'+h') - F(x, y, y')\ dx \\
&= \int_a^b F(x, y, y') + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(x, y, y') h + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y'}(x, y, y') h' - F(x, y, y') \ dx + \cdots \\
&= \int_a^b \frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(x, y, y') h + \frac{\delta F}{\delta y'}(x, y, y') h'\ dx + \cdots
\end{align}